# Error when I try to close WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a WPF application with C#, but when I try to close application I receive this error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException verificata
  _HResult=-2146233087
  _message='L'impostazione della proprietà 'System.Windows.Window.Title' ha generato un'eccezione.' numero riga '6' e posizione riga '3'.
  HResult=-2146233087
  IsTransient=false
  Message='L'impostazione della proprietà 'System.Windows.Window.Title' ha generato un'eccezione.' numero riga '6' e posizione riga '3'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=6
  LinePosition=3
  StackTrace:
       in System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
  InnerException: System.ArgumentException
       _HResult=-2147024809
       _message='' non è un valore valido per la proprietà 'Title'.
       HResult=-2147024809
       IsTransient=false
       Message='' non è un valore valido per la proprietà 'Title'.
       Source=WindowsBase
       StackTrace:
            in System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
            in System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
            in MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
```

> In English: Setting the property 'System.Windows.Window.Title' threw an exception. 'line number '6 'and line position '3'.
>   ...
>   '' is not a valid value for the 'Title'.

When I try to close application I call this method

```
public void ClosedGame(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(Close));
            return;
        }
        this.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        log.Error(exc);
    }

}
```

I don't know where the error is. Can you help me?

Comment: what's on line 6 of your xaml?

Comment: Is `ClosedGame` a button event handler? Is it possible that it is called by another Thread? Change the `if` statement to `if(!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())`. Does anything else happen on `Close`? It seems that soemthing goes wrong with the window title. Can you post the XAML? It would be helpful to have a rough translation of the error messages.

Comment: Please include your xaml

Comment: Thanks you, in my XAMl file I have an error. So I have fixed it then the application found when I try to Close it.

Comment: in that case either post your solution as an answer, or delete the question. As it stands now this is not informative for any future visitors.